# Laws of Exponents — why are these expressions equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Why does $1.7^{k} + 1.7^{k-1} = 1.7^{k-1}(1.7+1)$?

My prof used this for a proof involving the Fibonacci numbers, but I think my algebra might have been too shaky to understand this step. Totally my fault and I'm doing practice outside of class to remedy that. However, I do want to know what rules enable this relation? Or if someone can show the steps relating them I would appreciate that too.

Comment: What do you see when you multiply out the right hand side using the distributive law $a(b+c) = ab + ac$?

Comment: $1,7^k = 1.7*1.7^{k-1}$, like $x^3 = x*x^2$

Comment: OH! Can't believe I didn't see that! Thank you both so much, this makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a combination of a few algebraic rules.

$a*a*a=a^3$

Now multiply both sides by $a$

$a*a*a*a=a^4$

All the real numbers  $x\in R$,  except $0$, have an inverse, $x^{-1}$ so that $xx^{-1}=1$.

So $x*x=x^2$, then multiply by $x^{-1}$

$x*x(x^{-1})=x^2(x^{-1})$

$x=x^1$.

Hence the use of negative exponents to imply division.

There's also the distributive law.

$a(b+c)=ab+ac$

Comment: Thanks Turloc! If anyone looking at this needs the tl;dr, try the first two comments under the question